# How do I re-enable Cortana after disabling using registry edits?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I had disabled Cortana using registry edits as suggested [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/). Specifically, by going into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search.` and setting the key `AllowCortana` to `0`.

Now I want to re-enable Cortana. So, I reverted the above change but Cortana is not enabled on my computer. I still see the regular Windows Search. I cannot find Cortana in Settings app as well.

Please suggest an alternative way to re-enable Cortana.

Details:

- System: Windows 10 Pro - Build 1803 - Activated
- Region: India
- Language: English (United States)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to restart your computer after changing the registry key. If this doesn't work then try typing "sfc /scannow" into the command prompt without the quotation marks to repair any corrupted files.

Answer (score 0):

From the article you provided, we can see:

For Home Users: Disable Cortana via the Registry.

For Pro and Enterprise Users: Disable Cortana via Group Policy.

According to your description, your operating system is Windows 10 Pro, we try to cancel the registry setting, restart the computer to see if we can use Cortana.

If it does not work, then we view  local group policy if the **Allow Cortana** is **enabled** or **disabled**, if it is disabled, we can set it as enabled, then restart the computer to see if Cortana is re-enabled.

**Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search >Allow Cortana**